# Repeater databinder.eval double quotes

Tags: c#, databinder

I have a `repeater` like the following,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEntries" runat="server">                         
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now, I want to bind the Text value of `LinkButton`s with the following,

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EntryText") %>
```

However, I get the double quotes problems, when I do the following,

```
Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EntryText") %>"
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a combination of double and single quotes:

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EntryText") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
((ContainerType)Container.DataItem)).EntryText
```

So it'll look like this

```
Text='<%# ((ContainerType)Container.DataItem)).EntryText %>'
```

where ContainerType is the type of that object. It is actually more efficient that way because it won't have to be evaluated using the "Eval" method.

Otherwise use single quote followed by double quote.

Answer (score 1):

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EntryText") %>'
```

This may solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EntryText")%>'
```